# Putty Configuration GUI - remote command from script

Tags: ssh, putty

I can call Remote Command by local file from console(-m option) in putty.

Is it possible to do the same from Putty GUI(Connection->SSH->Remote command, or elsewhere)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to put it more clearly, the question is can we set a file as the source of the remote command in the gui.

Not directly, no - it explicitly takes only a string. Possibly one of the various putty forks has it added (although I can confirm kitty does not).

The only way I can think of to do it is to wrap putty in a script which reads the content of the file (whatever it is) and puts that value into the windows registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/SimonTatham/PuTTY/Sessions/NAMEOFSESSION/RemoteCommand` before executing putty.

Comment: You right, kitty does, but I need to use putty. What do you exactly mean "wrap putty in a script which reads the content of the file"?

Comment: I mean write a powershell script / batch file that:

 1. gets the contents of the script you want to have run.
 2. updates the registry at the key provided.
 3. invokes putty.
Then call this rather than putty

Comment: Yes this can solve the problem, but its too cumbrous. Anyway thank you for your response!